# concatenation of 2 variable in EL

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, el

How to make this in El :

```
${'&edit='+edit+'id='+id}
```

I try it but it didn't work. he make addition instead of concatenation !

Comment: I have no idea about the programming language you use but, in other languages, such string concatenation is achieved with the `&` (ampersand) operator. Maybe it'll work for you.

Comment: What is your EL version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not concatenate Strings like this in `EL`, unless you are using `EL 3.0`, 
In previous `EL` versions you can call concatenate method of each string.

Like this

```
${'&edit='.concat(edit).concat('id=').concat(id)}
```

In [`EL 3.0`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-el005.htm), you can do it like this

```
${'&edit=' += edit += 'id=' += id}
```

The `EL` version is related to supported version of the Servlet implementation in your Servlet Container you are using (e.g., Tomcat, JBoss) and the Servlet version defined in your `web.xml` file, for example:

Servlet 3.0 supports EL 2.2

Servlet 2.5 supports EL 2.1

Servlet 2.4 supports EL 2.0

If you are using Tomcat as your servlet container, please check this page which gives information about supported Java EE specs implementations (e.g., Servlet, JSP, EL)

http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: How can I know which version of `EL` i'm using ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use two EL expressions instead of one?

```
&edit=${edit}id=${id}
```

Comment: good idea but it will not work in my case So the answer of @fujy works or me : `${edit ? '?&edit=' += edit += '&id=' += id : ''}`